# How can I use the component of any other layout(other than defined in setContentView()) in another activity in android

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, layout

I'm working on an app in which i need to show some data in listview for that i've created an activity which is connected to the layout containing listview , for that listview i've created custom listitem. Now i need to access the components( Imageview) from custom list item in activity. Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this ?

This is the activity

```
package com.example.manishnegi.sharemyride;


public class RideMatched extends Activity {
int commentCount       = 0;
private List<GetRidesSummaryDetails> oslist = new ArrayList<GetRidesSummaryDetails>();
ListView rides_matchedListview;
ImageView hrate1,hrate2,hrate3,hrate4,hrate5;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ride_matched);
    hrate1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hrate1);
    hrate2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hrate2);
    hrate3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hrate3);
    hrate4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hrate4);
    hrate5=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hrate5);
    int l=0;
   String arr;
    JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
    Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(b!=null)
    {
     l=b.getInt("array_length");
        arr=b.getString("rides_array");
        try {
             array=new JSONArray(arr);
            Log.e("String to array ",array.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("String to array",e.getMessage());

        }

        Log.e("Number of matched",l+"");
    }
    rides_matchedListview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.rides_matchedListview);
    Second scnd = new Second();
    List<GetRidesSummaryDetails> detailsofrides = scnd.getallcomments(l,array);
    for (GetRidesSummaryDetails values :detailsofrides){
        String driver_imageget = values.getDriverimage();
        String driver_nameget = values.getDrivername();
        String pickup_get = values.getPickuptime();
        String ride_idget= values.getRideId();
        String rating_get = values.getRating();
        String vehicle_imageget = values.getVehicleImage();

        GetRidesSummaryDetails vehi = new GetRidesSummaryDetails();
        vehi.setDriverimage(driver_imageget);
        vehi.setDrivername(driver_nameget);
        vehi.setPickuptime(pickup_get);
        vehi.setRideId(ride_idget);
        vehi.setRating(rating_get);
        setRating(Integer.parseInt(rating_get));
        vehi.setVehicleImage(vehicle_imageget);
        oslist.add(vehi);
        commentCount++;
        rides_matchedListview.setAdapter(new RidesMatchedAdapter(RideMatched.this, 0, oslist));
        new RidesMatchedAdapter(RideMatched.this ,0, oslist).notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}

public void setRating(int rate)
{
    if (rate == 1) {
        hrate1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);


    }

    if (rate == 2) {
        hrate1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        hrate2.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);

    }

    if (rate == 3) {
        hrate1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        hrate2.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        hrate3.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);

    }

    if (rate == 4) {
        hrate1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        hrate2.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        hrate3.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        hrate4.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);

    }

    if (rate == 5) {
        hrate1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        hrate2.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        hrate3.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        hrate4.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        hrate5.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);

    }

}
}
```

This is the listview layout(ride_matched.xml)

[image: I've set this layout in my activity]

This is the custom list item

[image: I want to imageview of this layout in my activity]

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: do you want to access that child view(list item) when you click on it??

Comment: I've added the required code and image, now can u please help

Comment: I would be doing that but before that i need to change the rating imges on the basis of data how do i change those images?

Comment: you want to change your rating imges on the click of it or want only paint it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must've created the adapter for the listview using that adapter declare the images inside viewHolder it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use any adapter (according to your need) to inflate data in the ListView. In the adapter itself, you can access the components of custom listitem.
You cannot access the components of custom listitem inside the activity. They can only be accessed inside the adapter inflating the data in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass adapter to the listview. Adapters contain list of model object to be shown in list . You can create a custom adapter extending the base adapter. You can follow the below tutorial
http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

p[ay attention to getView method in the adapter and change the layout name as per you custom layout in the following line of get view
   vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);

Create a holder class where it has all the view item required to display in your list.
You need not to access Image view from activity as it can be accessed in the getView method for each row iteration.